# TLS session refresh - DROWN attack

Tags: tls, key

According to the full technical [paper](https://drownattack.com/drown-attack-paper.pdf) of DROWN attack,

> A typical scenario requires the attacker to observe 1,000 TLS
>   handshakes, then initiate 40,000 SSLv2 connections and perform 2 50
>   offline work to decrypt a 2048-bit RSA TLS ciphertext

Among theses 1,000 TLS handshakes, one will contains the premaster
secret decrypted, which will be used to retrieve the session key.

However, in my opinion, it will be useless if the TLS handshake is not the last one. 
In fact, after each TLS handshakes between the client and the server, the premaster secret will be different because the TLS session has refreshed...

Can you explain me why the TLS handshake containing the premaster
secret decrypted, even if it's not the last exchanged between the victim and the server, will still serve ?

Thanks.

Comment: The goal of DROWN is to decrypt an eavesdropped session, which can be complete, not to tamper or hijack it, which would require it still be open. Obviously this is useful only if the sensitive data in the decrypted session is moderately longterm, such as a login password rather than a session token with a 5-minute timeout.

Comment: So, can you explain me why you could use DROWN with MITM ? In that case, it's not only an eavesdropped session...

Comment: There are two MITM variants described in the paper: 'Special' DROWN in section 5 leverages a bug in OpenSSL if the server is using an outdated version to make the oracle *much* faster, fast enough to be realtime, although still only for a fraction of (victim TLS) handshakes, in which case the one handshake that is broken is still the 'current' one; and an attack on QUIC, a new protocol I haven't used yet and which apparently will be fixed before I do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, "fast enough to be realtime" helped me a lot. Also, when you say "broken", do you mean "stolen" ?

Comment: 'break' and its tenses like 'broken' in cryptography means an unauthorized party (called the adversary or attacker, or more colorful names) defeats the purpose intended to be achieved. Since the TLS handshake intends to establish secrecy (confidentiality) and integrity for subsequent session data, this attack which allows the adversary to learn the premaster secret and thus decrypt the data, and if active/MitM also to tamper with or forge it, is a 'break'.